# int pointer won't return, triggers SIGABRT

Tags: c, pointers

I am at my wits end with this code X( I can't seem to figure out why the pointer intarray in my code will not return and triggers SIGABRT... the pointer seems to have been assigned a value of 0x0000000100400000, so I have no idea why the code won't return that value...
Here is the relevant code from my array generating function as well as the struct I use and the pieces of main() that use it:

```
struct ArrAndInv {
    int *array;
    long inversionCount;
};


int * arrayGenerator(FILE *file, int size_of_array) {
    int *intarray = malloc(size_of_array * sizeof(int));
    char num[8];
    char c = '\0';
    int addnumber;
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < 8; j++) {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
                num[j] = c;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        num[j+1] = '\0';
        addnumber = atoi(num);
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            num[j] = '\0';
        }
        intarray[i] = addnumber;
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return intarray;
}


int main() {
    struct ArrAndInv arya;
    FILE *integerarray = fopen("/Users/MyName/Desktop/IntegerArray.txt", "r");
    int arraysize = 100000;

    // Some more code

    rewind(integerarray);
    arya.array = malloc(arraysize * sizeof(int));
    arya.array = arrayGenerator(integerarray, arraysize);

    // More code
}
```

I'm about to have a meltdown because this code has been full of annoying little technical problems (like I didn't know an integer array had to be allocated in the heap if it was 100000 integers - that error alone took quite a while to figure out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is on Linux since you're getting a SIGABRT?

First off, if you're collecting 8 ASCII digits and will process the resultant string using atoi, the array num needs to be declared to be 9 in size (char num[9]) so you can hold 8 digits as well as the null terminator. You're probably getting this error because you are going past the array bound of the stack variable.

While we're at it, a better practice might be to use fscanf instead of reading each character individually from a file:

```
fscanf(file, "%ld\n", &addnumber);
```

Second, if you originally allocated your intarray locally in the function, it would be located on the stack. So, you could well run into problems because stacks can only be so large. Large arrays should be allocated from the heap.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I forgot to mention that the integers being added max out at 100000, so there won't be any more than six digits. I'm using Xcode, which marked the line with SIGABRT. Thanks for clarifying the stack vs heap question as well! I thought malloc would automatically put it on the heap, but I didn't know the fact that it was in a function would prevent that. Using fscanf was what did the trick though! I'm not quite sure what the issue was with the fgetc method, but at this point I'm satisfied with having a successful run haha... Thanks so much :D

Comment: malloc will always return a chunk of memory from the heap. However, if you had allocated the array in the scope of the function, it would have been allocated off of the stack: `int intarray[1000000]`. This would certainly cause problems. Anyway, glad to be of help.

Comment: Actually, what I said in the previous comment about large stack variables is probably not entirely true in Linux. But it's a better practice to malloc large objects than to declare them locally off of the stack for portability.

Answer (score 1):

```
char num[8];
...
for (j=0; j < 8; j++) {
...
}
num[j+1] = '\0';
```

If that loop ever runs either 7 or 8 times, then the following statement writes beyond the bounds of `num`. Depending on the layout of the stack, that could perhaps corrupt your pointer or otherwise cause problems.

Comment: Seven times should be okay since that's `0..6` and `j+1` will be seven. The problem only occurs if the loop runs eight times.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the numbers in the file max out at 100000, and so will only have 6 digits at most. Although... now that you mention it, I was getting a random 0 in the array (which should only have numbers 1 through 100000), and I figured out that it was being inserted after 100000, so perhaps the loop did overrun there!